# AXIOS not working with Same Page with different query parameter Vue3

Tags: vue.js, axios, vuejs3, vue-router

HI i am facing an issue if i am on this route **http://127.0.0.1:8000/indexpage** then ajax request not works again for this route **http://127.0.0.1:8000/indexpage?subcategory_id=6**

i want product on basis of categories but if i am on same page then axios not works

here it is my code

```
       data(){
            return {

                gridProducts : [],
                loading : false,
            }
        },
       created()
        {   
            this.getData()
            
        },
        methods:{
            getData()
            {
                const req = axios.get(`/api/products?subcategory_id=${this.$route.query.subcategory_id ? this.$route.query.subcategory_id : null}`)
                        .then((response)=>{
                            this.gridProducts = response.data.products;
                        }).then(()=>{
                            this.loading = true;
                        })
            }
        }
```

thanks for any help :)

i try this

```
created()
        {   
            this.getData()
            
        },
        methods:{
            getData()
            {
                const req = axios.get(`/api/products?subcategory_id=${this.$route.query.subcategory_id ? this.$route.query.subcategory_id : null}`)
                        .then((response)=>{
                            this.gridProducts = response.data.products;
                        }).then(()=>{
                            this.loading = true;
                        })
            }
        }
```

Comment: Ideally your code looks fine to me and it works every time you will load the component. Can you please check the network request in the network tab of developer tool. I hope you are getting `this.$route.query.subcategory_id`

Comment: Shouldn't `this.loading = true;` be set above the request and then reset to false? You don't have to use a separate handling function to update your `this.loading` flag.

Comment: @RohìtJíndal yes i find the  subcategory id but when i am on  this route  [link](http://127.0.0.1:8000/indexpage)  http://127.0.0.1:8000/indexpage then click on  _http://127.0.0.1:8000/indexpage?subcategory_id=6_ **subcategory wise product router link** then  due to same page axios request not send due to same

Comment: @PeterKrebs yes  but issue is due to on same page subcategory link which is same as allproducts link just add query perameter axios not sent..  if my route is **http://127.0.0.1:8000/** then i click on **http://127.0.0.1:8000/indexpage?subcategory_id=11** then this route works but if i am on **http://127.0.0.1:8000/indexpage** page then click on this **http://127.0.0.1:8000/indexpage?subcategory_id=11*( not works

Comment: @UmerGhouri there are two different things - API call and application route. As API call will always trigger on an event and it will work with it respect to directory structure

Comment: @RohìtJíndal mean if i am on same  route then ajax request not send.. like if i am on  ** 127.0.0.1:8000 ** this route then click on same button which have this route ** 127.0.0.1:8000 ** then ajax not sent?

Comment: @UmerGhouri Ajax call runs in the background and there is no relation between the route and ajax call. It should work, no matter how many times you will call the same ajax from the same page/route (browser URI).